# Fill remaining height with Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a web page. My web page uses Bootstrap version 3. Currently, it looks something like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    Stuff here
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-8">
    Other stuff here
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div id="fillAvailableSpace">
      [Main content goes here]
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    Other text goes here
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-6 pull-right">
    Some text goes here
  </div>
</div>
```

I need the `div` with the id "fillAvailableSpace" to fill the available height of the screen with the exception of the size of the first row and the last row. How do I fill the remaining available height of a page with Bootstrap?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try something like below:

```
Element-name {
display: inline-flex;
height: 100%;
}
```